# Tab character in C# settings

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I'm trying to put a tab character like `\t` into the [settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx) of a C# application (as `char`).
I failed so far.
I also tried to use other serialization as [`Binary`or `XML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.serializationmode(v=vs.110).aspx)but didn't get it to work.

So my simple question is, are you somehow able to put the tab character into the application / user settings in C#?

UPDATE:

It's .NET 4.5.2

It appears, that also with the type `string` it's buggy. When I paste the tab from e.g. notepad++, it puts a new line plus some whitespace characters into the `app.config` but no tab character:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `&#09;` or `\\t` instead `\t` in config file

Comment: When I put this directly into the `App.config` and reopen the `Settings.settings` in UI, it recognizes a change and asks me to apply it to the `Settings.settings`. In the case of `\\t` it suggests an empty string, in the case of `&#09;` it actually suggests a tab but in the application I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: This works, if you use a `string` as type in the `Settings.settings`, but doesn't work when using the type `char`.

Answer (score 3):

To do it through the VS UI, Use a standard trick which works in almost all applications and cases, including this one: put a tab on the clipboard and then paste it into the target application.

Comment: It doesn't work. It puts an empty string into the App.config and if you reopen the Settings.settings in the UI, it's empty.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't work for you. I tested it in vs2015 immediately before posting my answer. I highly suspect you did it wrong. Perhaps explain with as much detail as you can the exact process you used to get the tab in the clipboard and paste it into VS's settings editor.

Comment: I added a new setting through the VS UI, put it to char with application code, made a tab in notepad ++, pasted it into the value and saved the `.settings` file. When I reopened the `.settings file` it mentioned, that the current value is empty string and if I would like to apply  the tab as value. This happens every time and the tab itself is never applied as value. Also in the `app.config` there is just an empty string in the value tags.

Comment: So you're adding a char type. You were never clear about that. I doubt anyone expected that. I tried this and the .settings file is NOT an empty string. Nor is the app.config file empty--however, it is a newline with a bunch of messed up indenting spaces. This seems like a bug and nothing you can do anything about. I suggest you use a string instead of a char.

Comment: You're right, it's not empty in the `app.config`, but it appears to be empty in the UI. Also it's empty when accessed during runtime. I'll update my question.

Comment: The string type is buggy (only in app.config) only when the complete contents is whitespace. You can workaround it by prefixing your entries with | or the like and trimming it when you fetch it from app.config

Answer (score 2):

For others which will looking for how to save 'TAB' or 'SPACE' etc in config...

You can simple use it's decimal value from ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/). So for example for space character it's value 32, for tab it's value 9. Some examples...:

**EXAMPLE 1:**

Save single tab in App.config

> config section:

```
<setting name="OneTabString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>9</value>
</setting>
```

> Application section:

```
char tab = Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.OneTabString));
string stringTab = tab.ToString();
```

**EXAMPLE 2:**

Save multi tab string in config (there is a lot of ways how to do it, but for example...)

> Config section

```
<setting name="MultiTabString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>9;9;9;9;9</value>
</setting>
```

> Application section:

```
char[] tabs = Properties.Settings.Default.MultiTabString.GetCharsByDecimal(new char[] { ';' });
string stringTabs = string.Join(string.Empty, tabs);

//Extension method for getting chars by decimal from our string
public static char[] GetCharsByDecimal(this string inputString, char[] delimiters)
    {
        int[] charsDecimals = inputString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        char[] resultChars = new char[charsDecimals.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < charsDecimals.Length; i++)
        {
            resultChars[i] = Convert.ToChar(charsDecimals[i]);
        }

        return resultChars;
    }

//Or safer variant of our extension method
public static char[] GetCharsByDecimal(this string inputString)
    {
        int[] charsDecimals = Regex.Split(inputString, @"\D+").Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        char[] resultChars = new char[charsDecimals.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < charsDecimals.Length; i++)
        {
            resultChars[i] = Convert.ToChar(charsDecimals[i]);
        }

        return resultChars;
    }
```

**EXAMPLE 3:**

Save delimiters (including tab) in config

> Config section

```
<setting name="Delimiters" serializeAs="Xml">
  <value>
    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <string>59</string>
      <string>44</string>
      <string>9</string>
      <string>45</string>
      <string>124</string>
      <string>32</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
  </value>
</setting>
```

> Application section

```
char[] delimiters = Properties.Settings
                              .Default
                              .Delimiters
                              .Cast<string>()
                              .Select(s => Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(s))).ToArray();
```